# Get django to render python generated html passed via context parameter?

Tags: python, html, django

I want to take a list of data, and build a square (or near to square) block of < div> elements containing that data for rendering in an html page using django.

I've written some code that builds a square (ish) block of elements, and colours them randomly based on some input supplied as a list.

```
from math import sqrt, pow
import random

colour_index = {
    1 : 'bg-color-primary-0',
    2 : 'bg-color-primary-1',
    3 : 'bg-color-primary-2',
    4 : 'bg-color-primary-3',
    5 : 'bg-color-primary-4',
    6 : 'bg-color-secondary-0',    
    7 : 'bg-color-secondary-1',
    8 : 'bg-color-secondary-2',
    9 : 'bg-color-secondary-3',
    10 : 'bg-color-tertiary-4',
    11 : 'bg-color-tertiary-0',
    12 : 'bg-color-tertiary-1',
    13 : 'bg-color-tertiary-2',
    14 : 'bg-color-tertiary-3',
    15 : 'bg-color-tertiary-4'
}

width_class = {
    1 : 'width100pc',
    2 : 'width50pc',
    3 : 'width33pc',
    4 : 'width25pc',
    5 : 'width20pc',    
    6 : 'width16pc',
    7 : 'width14pc',
    8 : 'width12pc',
    9 : 'width11pc',
    10: 'width10pc'
}

def nextSQR(anumber):
    if (sqrt(anumber))==int(sqrt(anumber)):
        return pow(int(sqrt(anumber)),2)
    else:
        return pow(int(sqrt(anumber)+1),2)

def targetshape(anumber):
    return (sqrt(nextSQR(anumber)),sqrt(nextSQR(anumber)))

def divgrid(content_list):
    dstring = ""
    targ_shape = targetshape(len(content_list))
    w = targ_shape[0]
    for a in content_list:
        r = random.randrange(1,10)
        dstring = dstring + "<div class=\"" + colour_index.get(r) + " " + width_class.get(w) + "\">" + a + "</div>"
    return dstring
```

In my views.py page, I get my elements from the database into a list, send the list through divgrid(), and pass the results into my context:

```
def home(request):
    stuff_list = testContent.objects.all()
    l = [a.name for a in stuff_list]
    mgl = mg.divgrid(l)
    context = {'grid' : mgl}
    return render(request, "test.html", context)
```

That in turn feeds the generation of an html page through the double-courly brackets variable notation {{ grid }}

All this works fine - except, instead of seeing the results all nicely formatted within their organising div blocks, I see the html-text displayed verbatim on my page like so:

```
<div class="bg-color-primary-3 width33pc">Tom Kimber</div><div class="bg-color-secondary-0 width33pc">Tom</div><div class="bg-color-secondary-1 width33pc">Tom</div><div class="bg-color-primary-1 width33pc">Tom</div><div class="bg-color-secondary-3 width33pc">Tom</div><div class="bg-color-primary-1 width33pc">Lisa</div><div class="bg-color-primary-2 width33pc">Bobby Tables</div>
```

How do I get django to interpret my generated html code as code (i.e. rendering the divs as divs, resulting in the element-content being appropriately formatted) and not as text to be displayed as-is?

Comment: Use the `|safe` filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark the string returned by `divgrid()` as safe:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

def divgrid(content_list):
    ...
    return mark_safe(dstring)
```

You can then output the context variable as HTML without the need for the `|safe` filter:

```
{{ grid }}
```

Comment: Thankyou, I'm weighing up the pros and cons of picking one way over the other, and feel this one is the tidier of the two - then again, the filter is fairly neat too - any thoughts on a method of referencing images that normally requires a template call? (see my comment to Burhan above)

Comment: You could use `django.templatetags.static.static(path)` directly.

Answer (score 2):

By default, and for security reasons - content passed to templates is considered unsafe and is escaped.

So `<` becomes `&lt;` etc.; the end result being that your HTML is rendered instead of being parsed.

To prevent this use the [`safe` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) to mark variables as "safe to parse" so django will not automatically escape their contents.

In your template `{{ grid|safe }}`.

Comment: OK, that's great - I've got it working nicely now :) Here's a follow-up question - If I want to reference content that's in my static directory i.e. images, that's normally done using a template method like `<img src="{% static 'img/holygrail.png' %}" />` but if I pass that through the 'safe' filter, it gets rendered without being templated, resulting in an error - is there a halfway house between the two where I can generate template-parseable code? (I know, tall order, but if I wanted to serve images programatically, this might be one way to do it)

Comment: Comments are not for discussions. Please open a new question (you can link to this one) and close this question. StackOverflow is not designed as a discussion forum.